# IntelliJ IDEA refuses to work after changing directory in which I make Java projects

Tags: java, intellij-idea, compilation, jetbrains-ide

For months now, I have been using IntelliJ IDEA to write my Java projects. I have always made them in the same directory, and never had any problems with the IDE.

However, after starting a new college course of OOP in Java, I decided to save all my college projects in a seperate directory. To my surpirse, IntelliJ IDEA simply REFUSED to compile any projects made here.

The specific error I get is:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class Main
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Main

Process finished with exit code 1
```

It suggests 'rebuilding the project', which results in the following:

```
Internal error (java.io.IOException): Cannot find IntelliJ IDEA project files at C:\IMPERIUM ROMANUM\Fakultet Tehnickih Nauka\Semestar II\Objektno Orijentisano Programiranje I\Vežbe\VEZBE_00 et VEZBE_01\Vezbe01
java.io.IOException: Cannot find IntelliJ IDEA project files at C:\IMPERIUM ROMANUM\Fakultet Tehnickih Nauka\Semestar II\Objektno Orijentisano Programiranje I\Vežbe\VEZBE_00 et VEZBE_01\Vezbe01
    at org.jetbrains.jps.model.serialization.JpsProjectLoader.loadProject(JpsProjectLoader.java:124)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.model.serialization.JpsProjectLoader.loadProject(JpsProjectLoader.java:101)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.model.serialization.impl.JpsSerializationManagerImpl.loadModel(JpsSerializationManagerImpl.java:23)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.JpsModelLoaderImpl.loadModel(JpsModelLoaderImpl.java:34)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildRunner.load(BuildRunner.java:68)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.runBuild(BuildSession.java:347)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.run(BuildSession.java:193)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildMain$MyMessageHandler.lambda$channelRead0$0(BuildMain.java:211)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1144)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:642)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1589)

Please perform full project rebuild (Build | Rebuild Project)
```

This is incredibly frustrating, since we are talking about the simplest possible "Hello World" code, which has 0 complexity and doesn't even use any other classes except Main.

What's funny is that this same code compiles perfectly through the command prompt with
`javac Main.java`

and runs without any issues with
`java Main`

Does anyone have any similar experiences? Why is IntelliJ behaving like this, while working fine in all previous projects?

Comment: You need to tell IntelliJ what the "sources root" folder(s) is/are, that is, the root of the source tree.  You should be able to do that in your project window - right-click on the folder, and select "Mark Directory As" | "Sources Root".

Comment: Dawood's suggestion should be right here. See here for details: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/content-roots.html